# Creating dynamic dropdown buttons

Tags: php

I have two tables in my database

movie-> movie_id, movie_title

screening-> scr_id, movie_id, scr_date, scr_start

I am trying to make three dependent dropdown lists like this where date and time are automatically shown in the list according to the movie chosen.
[Dropdown list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELynZ.png) 
I have called a javascript function above my select list like this

```
<?php
     include_once("class/db_inc.php");
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#movie').change(function() {
                    var id=$(this).val();
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "&id="+id+"&get_date=1",   
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                    $("#date").append(html);
                    } 
                    });
                    });


                    $('#timeime').change(function() {
                    var id=$(this).val();
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    data: "&id="+id+"&get_time=1",   
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                    $("#time").append(html);
                    } 
                    });
                    });
                </script>
    <select class="list_of_movies" name="movie" id="movie"><option value="">Select Movie</option>
                  <?php
                     $res=$schedule->getmoviedetail();
                        while ($row=$connect->fetchArray($res))
                        {
                          $movie_id=$row['movie_id'];
                          $title=$row['movie_title'];
                          echo "<option value='$movie_id'>$title</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
    </select>

                        <select class="list_of_movies" name="date" id="date"><option value="">Select Date</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="list_of_movies" name="time" id="time" ><option value="">Select Time</option></select> 
                       <div class="tab_desc">
                       <a href="movie-select-show.html">Book Now</a>
                       </div>
```

And my ajax.php goes like this

```
<?php 
include_once("class/db_inc.php");

if($_REQUEST['get_date']){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `screening`  where `movie_id`=".$_REQUEST['id']);
 $date="";
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
      $sid=$row['scr_id'];
      $sdate=$row['scr_date'];

      $date.= "<option value='".$sid."'>".$sdate."</option>";
    }
echo $date;
}

elseif($_REQUEST['get_time']){
$time="";
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `screening`  where `movie_id`=".$_REQUEST['id']);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
      $sid=$row['scr_id'];
      $stime=$row['scr_start'];

     $time.= "<option value='".$sid."'>".$stime."</option>";
    }
echo $time;
}
?>
```

The first dropdown shows the movie list fine. But the second and third dropdown are completely not working. I am stuck at this for a day now. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did u find the issue..

Comment: And I suggested to use mysqli_* or PDO becuase   mysql_* deprecated and close in php 7

Comment: @devpro nope i've been stuck here for a day. Neither the code works properly nor it throws any errors. I am kinda beginner with php and ajax.

Comment: Chk what I suggest in answer

Comment: @devpro I corrected that like the way i edited above. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in `HTML.` You didn't close your **movie** `<select>` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
  $('#movie').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); 

    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "ajax.php", 
      data: {
        id: id,
        get_date: 1
      },    
      success: function(html) { 
        $("#date").append(html); 
      }  
    }); 
  });

  $('#date').change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax ({ 
      type: "POST", 
      url: "ajax.php", 
      data: {
        id: id,
        get_time: 1
      },    
      success: function(html) {
        $("#time").append(html); 
      }
    }); 
  });  
});
</script>
```

You should also correct your PHP to avoid SQL Injections. Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: there is still no success. Am i doing something wrong in my coding?

Comment: @bishal.bh Do you have any Javascript errors? Do you have any PHP warnings/errors?

Comment: there are no errors. The second and third dropdowns just do not show any options.

Comment: Do you have any errors/warnings during ajax requests?

Comment: None. 2nd and 3rd drop down buttons just look static. Is there any way i can test if my ajax request is going right?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Developer Tools

Comment: I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: Is there anyway i can do this with only php without the use of ajax?